# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1

Tags: sql

First of all, I'm new to the club and must say I find it a very interesting site, and it has really helped me a lot with my coding experiences in C#. Thanks for that.

On a total different note, I'm getting the follow error at one of our customers (we resell document management software). And I'm trying to determine if this error message as stated below can cause performance issues.

Google'ing this error message has already informed me that it can be caused when using Reserved Words as Column Names.

> 24-4-2012 11:16:49 [ERROR]    :There was an error parsing the query. [
>   Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 77,Token in error = 66667 ]
>   UPDATE WS_LOCATION SET Frequency = @FreqParams, LUTime =
>   @LUTimeParams, Client = '', Matter = '' WHERE WSLoc_ID = '22' occured
>   on InsertIntoLocationTables.

I'm not very familiar with all of the Reserved Words in SQL, perhaps any of you can help me out with determining what is the cause of this error?

It's a local SQL Compact database bytheway (.sdf).

Answer (score 1):

Enclosing your names with brackets will prevent the error of using T-SQL reserved words.

```
UPDATE [WS_LOCATION] SET
[Frequency] = @FreqParams,
[LUTime] = @LUTimeParams,
[Client] = '',
[Matter] = ''
WHERE [WSLoc_ID] = '22';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with reserved words, prefix your column names with the table name :

```
UPDATE WS_LOCATION 
SET WS_LOCATION.Frequency = @FreqParams, WS_LOCATION.LUTime = @LUTimeParams, WS_LOCATION.Client = '', WS_LOCATION.Matter = '' 
WHERE WS_LOCATION.WSLoc_ID = '22'
```

Comment: @BasvanderLinden I'm currently doing some garbage collection on my useless answers, but this one looks to have been helpful, even if you never validated it. Please accept the answer :)

Comment: @LeGrandMere, sorry but I can't :-) I need 15 reps myself in order to vote for others :-)

Comment: @BasvanderLinden : Hahaha :) I'm not sure that you need some rep to accept the answer, which is different from upvoting ;)